# Webpack produces weird sourcemaps

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have an Electron app setup with TypeScript, Webpack & React.

However, when I try to click on a link in the stacktraces, it's not working as the links starts with "webpack-internal:///./src/"

I have tried to switch webpack devtool to "source-map", but then it only points to the generated .js file instead of the .ts file.

How can I fix this ?

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const globalConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  resolve: {
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: "tsconfig.json" })],
    extensions: ['.ts'],
  },
}

const mainConfig = {      
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  target: 'electron-main',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts$/,
      include: /src/,
      use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader' }]
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index.js'
  }
}

const rendererConfig =     {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/renderer/react.tsx',
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  module: { rules: [{
    test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
    include: /src/,
    use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader' }]
  }] },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/renderer',
    filename: 'react.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/renderer/index.html'
    })
  ]
}

module.exports = [
  Object.assign({}, globalConfig, mainConfig),
  Object.assign({}, globalConfig, rendererConfig),
];
```

Here is my tsconfig.json just in case :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "moduleResolution": "node", // Required for es2022 module aliases
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true, // Allows import statements
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "paths": {
            "common/*": ["common/*"],
            "interfaces/*": ["common/interfaces/*"],
            "main/*": ["main/*"],
            "renderer/*": ["renderer/*"],
        },
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
}
```